# Why does typescript narrow unknown to never inside a reachable conditional block?

Tags: typescript

When inputting the sample below in Typescript Playground ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANiA5gSQGYDEQhgXhgClSwC4YBXMAazBAHcwBKUgNxAEsATXAPhgG8AsACgYMNqgJFsbSFACGYYAFMQEgPIAjAFZLgsAGT6YAIg1yATsbFgYUhv2GjRoSCDhKAdAkSEsDANyOMAC+wqFCwt5omCD4fCZmlqSmcgBeVsEBQA)), mousing over `foo` inside the `console.log` statement reveals that `foo`'s type has been narrowed to `never`. But it seems this cannot be the case, since running `logIfFoo` as in the below will indeed result in `console.log(foo)` being called. What is the explanation behind this?

```
const logIfFoo = (foo: unknown): void => {
  if (foo instanceof Object && "bar" in foo) {
    console.log(foo);
  }
}

logIfFoo({ "bar": "baz" });
```

Comment: An `Object` doesn't have a built-in `bar` property, so TS thinks the `in` will never be fulfilled. In this sort of situation I usually assert the object is of type `{[prop: string]: unknown}`

Comment: Is `foo instanceof Object` not equivalent to `typeof foo == "object" && foo !== null`?

Comment: It's as if you did `foo instanceof Car && "rudder" in Car`; it can't keep track of every subclass of `Car`, so when it sees a property that isn't just in `Car`, it assumes there is no type that works. It's arguable that it would be better to have `foo` restricted to `Car & { rudder: unknown }`, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is an [outstanding issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38608). There is a [pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/38610) that has been approved and is awaiting merge.